# The font is not working, when i run the program

Tags: python, tkinter, fonts

I ran the program, but the font that shows up is the standard python tkinter font, instead of the font i had chose

all my imports and libraries chosen are there, I don't know what the problem is as this is my first time importing a font to python tkinter

```
def menu():
    def sign_up_clicked():
        menu_window.destroy()
        sign_up()
    def login_clicked():
        menu_window.destroy()
        login()
    def stop():
        menu_window.destroy()
        exit()
    def draw_clicked():
        user_pen.main_process()
    
    pyglet.font.add_file('menu_font.ttf')

    menu_window = tk.Tk()
    menu_window.title('Main Menu')
    menu_window.config(bg = '#4F4C50', width = 100)

    menu_frame = tk.Frame(menu_window)
    menu_frame.config(bg='#4F4C50')
    menu_frame.grid(column = 0, row = 0, padx= 10, pady=10, sticky='w')

    menu_heading = tk.Label(menu_frame, text='Menu')
    menu_heading.config(bg='white', font = ('menu_font', 24), \
                        width = 60, height=2)
    menu_heading.grid(column = 0, row = 0)

    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("Mossy education.png"))

    brand_heading = tk.Label(menu_frame, image= img)
    brand_heading.grid(column = 2, row = 0)

    login_user= tk.Button(menu_frame, text='Login', command=login_clicked)
    login_user.config(bg='#14cae3', font = ('menu_font', 24), \
                        width = 14, height=2)
    login_user.grid(column = 0, row = 2, pady=15, padx= 15, sticky='w')

    sign_user= tk.Button(menu_frame, text='Sign Up', command=sign_up_clicked)
    sign_user.config(bg='#14cae3', font = ('menu_font', 24), \
                        width = 14, height=2)
    sign_user.grid(column = 0, row = 3, pady=15, padx= 15, sticky='w')

    stop_user= tk.Button(menu_frame, text='Exit', command=stop)
    stop_user.config(bg='#14cae3', font = ('menu_font', 24), \
                    width = 14, height=2)
    stop_user.grid(column = 0, row = 4, pady=15, padx= 15, sticky='w') 
    menu_window.mainloop()
```

This is the code i have

Comment: AFAIK, `font=('name', size)` tries to import a font from the system fonts. Obviously you can't use a font defined in another module by only passing its name. You will need to set the font another way. I don't know if there is a built-in way to do this, but my best guess is you read both `tkinter` and `pyglet` source codes and find a low-level way to send data from one to the other.

Comment: What is your platform?

Comment: Note that the *font name* may not be the same as the filename of the font.